# Testing Database Results

Tags: java, testing, junit

How can I write JUnit tests for CRUD operations of an application(**Java** application). I use MyBatis as data mapper over database.
For example I have a query as this:

```
SELECT * FROM sm.PERSON WHERE name='something'
```

And I call this query from MyBatis:

```
java.util.List<Person> persons = SqlMapClient.openSession().queryForList(queryName)
```

Now how can I test this operation to get that the result is right?

---

(Another thing please tell me title of books for learning Testing in java. I know the basics and I want to get deeper.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your Junit test should run standalone without depending on database results. 
In your case you need to test using the database, you can use [DbUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/%20dbunit), an junit extension targeted for database-driven projects.

For the ebook :

1. Unit testing : [JUnit In Action](http://www.manning.com/massol/)
2. Regression test : [Selenium](http://selenium-tutorial.blogspot.com/2012/03/selenium-tutorial.html)

Comment: I'll look for DBUnit, but what do you mean by this sentence:"Junit test should run standalone without depending on database results". Does it mean that I should not use JUnit for database results?

Comment: If external system (like database server) is involved in testing, i think it's more like regression testing. See http://www.javaranch.com/unit-testing.jsp

Answer (score 1):

Here, it seems that you want to `test MyBatis's functionality` of its CRUD functions using JUnit. What I would have done is, `use the native JDBC` which is an established standard to fire the query over the database and `then compare the` result with what the `MyBatis function` gives.

For your second question, if you are using `JUnit 3`, then use `JUnit in Action first edition` and if using `JUnit 4`, use `JUnit in Action second edition`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I got answer of my first question. :)  But about my second question I want to know more about other kinds of testing, like Customer Test, Acceptance Test and so on. But I think that JUnit in Action deals with unit testing.

Answer (score 1):

First question: testing of the persistence layer is not easy. You should read chapter 17 in Junit in Action 2nd edition. [Unitils](http://www.unitils.org/cookbook.html) could be also help.

Books about Testing:

- [Junit in Action 2nd](http://www.manning.com/tahchiev/)
- [Test Driven - 
  Practical TDD and Acceptance TDD for Java Developers](http://www.manning.com/koskela/) (one of my favorites)
- [xUnit Test Patterns](http://xunitpatterns.com/) (Somehow a must have)
- [Practical Unit Testing](http://practicalunittesting.com/) (Well written using TestNG and Mockito, quite new)
- [Kent Beck about Test Driven Development](https://www.google.ch/search?q=beck%20test%20driven%20development)